# Accessing mtp/ptp device from python script, permission denied

Tags: permissions, python, android, mtp

I have my Android mobile connected to my Ubuntu 20.10 machine. I am trying to set the 'last modified' timestamp on all files within the DCIM/Camera directory using `os.utime`. I receive the python error `OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported` which is basically a permission denied.

- The python script is tested and definitely works on other directories. Path is definitely correct.
- The phone is connected just fine and I can access my files from within any other program.
- I am the owner of the files.
- Permissions are rw--. Trying to chmod them yields permission denied.
- Sudoing the python script does not help.
- Preparing the files elsewhere and copying them over did not do the trick as the copy operation seems to modify the mtime.

What can I do? Why does this mtp mount behave to differently than anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is desired behavior: MTP and PTP implementations are designed to retain singular filesystem handling capabilities in the hands of the connected device with the connected device and the computer being in a server-client hierarchy, the connected device being the server. Although protocol definitions are not easily available there seems to be a handshake of the following form

Receive:

- physically connect device
- open storage memory
- device performs a directory traversal and provides tree and file lists to computer
- computer sends a file download request
- device sends a copy of the requested file
- a list of files is forwarded and the connection is closed while waiting for a response.

Send:

- a file transfer request is sent
- the Android device accepts it
- device receives file in a buffer and actively integrates it into its own fs tree in the desired location.

This makes direct access to file properties like exif meta data and cdate/ mdate attributes, as you would intuitively expect from a ftp-like connection or a true usb mass storage, impossible and explains the failure to change the fs permissions on the remote device.

**tl;dr** It's a feature not a bug. Wontfix.